# How to add shopping cart with vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I try to add shopping cart，but I do not know how to do it. When `count = 0`,`-` is hidden.And when `count > 0`,`-` is show.When i try to click `+`, automatically increase 1, click `-` automatically reduced by 1. But can not be displayed.[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhouyulong/L1x1u2tm/)

Look at the Javascript file:

```js
const goods = [{
  id: "1",
  goods_name: "水立方",
  goods_price: "30.00",
  goods_num: "15",
  count:"0"
}, {
  id: "2",
  goods_name: "农夫山泉",
  goods_price: "28.00",
  goods_num: "10",
  count:"0"
}]

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    list: goods,
  },
  methods: {
  addCart(item,event) {
        if (!this.item.count) {
          Vue.set(this.item, 'count', 1);
        } else {
          this.item.count++;
        }
      },
  lessCart(event) {
        this.item.count--;
      }   
  }
})
```

HTML file:

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list">
      <p>{{item.goods_name}}</p>
      <p>{{item.goods_price}}</p>
      <a v-show="item.count > 0" @click.stop.prevent="lessCart(item,$event)">-</a>
      <input v-show="item.count > 0" v-model="item.count">
      <a @click.stop.prevent="addCart(item,$event)">+</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the same state each time and not the state from the list.

You should simply do:

```js
   const goods = [{
  id: "1",
  goods_name: "水立方",
  goods_price: "30.00",
  goods_num: "15",
  count:"0"
}, {
  id: "2",
  goods_name: "农夫山泉",
  goods_price: "28.00",
  goods_num: "10",
  count:"0"
}]

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    list: goods,
  },
  methods: {
    addCart(item) {
      item.count++;
    },
    lessCart(item) {
      item.count--;  
     }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
<li v-for="item in list">
  <p>{{item.goods_name}}</p>
  <p>{{item.goods_price}}</p>
  <a v-show="item.count > 0" @click.stop.prevent="lessCart(item)">-</a>
  <input v-show="item.count > 0" v-model="item.count">
  <a @click.stop.prevent="addCart(item)">+</a>
</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note that you do not need the event argument in your method.